# VHDL loop only takes one bit into account

Tags: loops, vhdl

I am pretty much of a beginner in VHDL, so please don't mind me if the question seems silly, and please tell me if I'm not complying with the rules of this forum.
I haven't found the same problem on the Internet yet, though.

Here, I have a huge register (1600 bits), where I want to write a 64-bit block. The address of the block is determined by the bits of theta_io_ctrl.
theta_reg_bus_out is a 64-bit std_logic_vector.

```
    i1               <= 64*to_integer(unsigned(theta_io_ctrl(10 downto 6)));
    for i in 63 downto 0 loop
          i12            <= i1+i;
          next_mem2(i12) <= theta_reg_bus_out(i);
        end loop;  -- i
```

The issue with this code is, that it only takes into account the bit 0, and not the others.
Here, Modelsim tells me that theta_reg_bus_out= 00000000000000D3. 
However, when I check what's in next_mem2 at the corresponding address, I get 0000000000000001.

I also tried writing "0 to 63" instead. Then, it only takes into account the bit 63.

Where am I wrong ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

`i1` and `i12` must be signals, because you are assigning to them with a signal assignment. (Next time you ask a question, it would be better to construct an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Signals are not variables:

i) they are not updated until all processes suspend (either hit a `wait` statement or drop off the bottom)

ii) if you reassign a value to a signal before all processes suspend, it just overwrites the previous value assigned.

So, in your code, when this line (`i12 <= i1+i;`) is executed, the signal `i1` has yet to be updated. Then, in your loop, all the previous assignments to signal `i12` are overwritten by the assignment on the last iteration of your loop. This is why "it only takes into account the bit 0" or bit 63 if you use `0 to 63`.

So, either make `i1` and `i12` *variables*. Variables in VHDL behave like variables in any other language and are updated immediately. (You will have to do some googling to find out about variables, you cannot literally just replace one with the other because the assignment operator is different and variables can only be declared within a process.)

Or just simplify your code to something like:

```
for i in 63 downto 0 loop
  next_mem2(i+64*to_integer(unsigned(theta_io_ctrl(10 downto 6)))) <= theta_reg_bus_out(i);
end loop;  -- i
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply !
i1 and i12 are indeed signals here. I will try your quick solution first, and if it doesn't work, I'll look into the variables.